# Finding Distinct Value using SQL

Tags: sql

Show the titles and the award amounts of 20 awards that contain words discover, discoverer, discovery, discovered, and discovering in their abstracts.

My query:

```
SELECT title, count(award), abstract
FROM poop
ORDER BY award
WHERE abstract LIKE discov%
LIMIT 20
```

[image: ike table]

It doesnt like my where clause... Anyone? (In mySQL)

Comment: We ask for academic honesty, tag it with `homework`. If this does not apply to you, apologies, please ignore the comment.

Comment: I don't see an 'abstract' column ...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the single quotes around your criteria, you are only looking for words that *start* with "discov", your order by clause is in the wrong place, and you are using a count() expression without grouping by the other non-aggregate fields.  In order to fix this and look for words *containing* "discov", use this:

```
SELECT title, abstract, count(award),  
FROM table 
WHERE abstract 
LIKE '%discov%' 
GROUP BY title, abstract
ORDER BY count(award) 
LIMIT 20
```

If you truly did mean to just look for words starting with "discov", then use this:

```
SELECT title, abstract, count(award),  
FROM table 
WHERE abstract 
LIKE 'discov%'
GROUP BY title, abstract
ORDER BY count(award) 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: This gives an error in phpmyadmin: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE abstract LIKE 'discov%' LIMIT 20' at line 4'

Comment: @woopie I missed that your order by clause was in the wrong place at first; I've corrected this.  Try it now.

Comment: @woopie Actually, hold on...I just noticed you are using a count() function, too, without a group by clause.  I have fixed the query once more to address this.  You cannot use a count() expression without grouping by the other fields you are selecting.

Answer (score 1):

This query assumes distinct awards per pi.

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct award), pi 
FROM [tablename] 
GROUP BY pi 
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct award) DESC
```

States with top number of awards.

```
SELECT TOP 20 COUNT(distinct award), state
FROM [tablename]
GROUP BY state
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct award)
```

Remove the TOP 20 if you are not using T-SQL.

Comment: @woopie: you didn't mention which RDBMS you're using. Notice the caveat in the answer?  Remove the `TOP 20` and use `LIMIT 0,20`

Answer (score 1):

missing '' around discov and `ORDER BY` and `WHERE` are inversed:

```
SELECT title, count(award) AS count_award, abstract 
  FROM table 
 WHERE abstract LIKE 'discov%'
 GROUP BY title, abstract
 ORDER BY count_award DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table WHERE abstract LIKE 'discov%' ORDER BY award LIMIT 20' at line 2