# Finding Value in Sql with LIKE

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding Distinct Value using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545102/finding-distinct-value-using-sql)

Show the titles and the award amounts of 20 awards that contain words discover, discoverer, discovery, discovered, and discovering in their abstracts.

My query:

```
SELECT title, count(award), abstract
FROM table
ORDER BY award
WHERE abstract LIKE discov%
LIMIT 20
```

[image: ike table]

It doesnt like my where clause... Anyone? (In mySQL)